# Overload return type with template specialization?

Tags: c++, overloading, template-specialization

```
class Base
{
public:
    string Test() { return "hi"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int Test() { return 3; }
}
```

I want "hi" from Base. How is it possible to get `string s = Derived().Test()` to work? And no, `Test` has no parameters.

I tried `using Base::Derived`, but it seems that overloaded functions that only differ in return types are not inherited/exposed. I cannot reference `Base` from the client code, since `Base` will be template generated. The client knows the type it wants. I couldn't get `Test<string>()` to work through inheritance either.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not overloading, but hiding.

You need to cast back to the base class.

```
Derived d;
d.Test();  //calls Derived::Test()
static_cast<Base>(d).Test(); //calls Base::Text()
```

You can't overload functions based on return type:

#### 1.3.11 signature

> the information about a function that participates in overload
> resolution (13.3): its parameter-type-list (8.3.5) and, if the
> function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function
> itself and the class in which the member function is declared. [...]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on C++11 , you can do :

```
class Base
{
public:
    string Test() { return "hi"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    template<typename T= decltype(Test())>
    T Test() { return Base::Test(); }
};
```

check: http://ideone.com/blXhN

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `string s = Derived().Base::Test();`

Your compiler won't go on a quest through base types, but it will find the right function if you tell it where to look.